# Export data from Access table to Word table

Tags: ms-access, office-interop, export-to-word

I have Access data I'm trying to export to a Word table. The table has 3 columns, the first row and first column are all headers.

I'm trying to loop through the recordset and populate columns 2 & 3 with data. I'm able to start at row 2 and populate columns 2 and 3, but I cannot figure out how to move to the next row.

```
 iTbl = 1
 irow = 2
 iCol = 1

 Do Until recSet2.EOF
    If irow > wDoc.Tables(iTbl).Rows.Count Then
        wDoc.Tables(iTbl).Rows.Add
    End If

    For Each fld In recSet2.Fields
        On Error Resume Next
        iCol = iCol + 1
        wDoc.Tables(iTbl).Cell(irow, iCol).Range.Text = Nz(fld.Value)
    Next fld
    recSet2.MoveNext
    irow = irow + 1
    iCol = 1
 Loop
```

Comment: Please provide the full relevant code - there is a `Loop` at the end without a `Do While`. -- Proper indentation will also help you to see what is going on.

Comment: I edited the original post @Andre

Comment: I'd suggest first declaring all your variables (maybe add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module), and also get rid of `On Error Resume Next` - telling VBA to ignore errors isn't a good way to find the source of a problem.  Also I believe you'll need a `.MoveFirst` before you can use a `.MoveNext`, you can google those commands and there are hundreds fo examples for different situations

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems with your code. As ashleedawg wrote, remove `On Error Resume Next`. If that doesn't help, please add to your question: what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Please add the first 3 or 4 rows of input, and also show the output your are getting. And tell us what is missing or what the output should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys. I managed to figure it out and works very well. It wouldn't move down to the next row and was attempting to write data to column(4) which doesn't exist, then throwing an error. Here is the code I used:

```
iTbl = 1
iRow = 2
iCol = 1

For Each fld In recSet2.Fields
iCol = iCol + 1
    If iCol < 4 Then
        wDoc.Tables(iTbl).Cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text = Nz(fld.value)
    Else
        If iCol > 3 Then
            iCol = iCol - 2
            iRow = iRow + 1
            wDoc.Tables(iTbl).Cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text = Nz(fld.value)
        End If
    End If
Next fld
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create a table in Word, especially one with a lot of data, is to first write the data into a character-delimited string format. Assign the string to a Range in Word, then use the ConvertToTable method to turn it into a table. That will save a lot of trouble with manipulating the object model and is the most efficient approach (fastest in execution).

The following code demonstrates this principle. The procedure `Test` creates a new instance of Word, creates a new document in the Word application then assigns the character-delimited string to the document content. This is then turned into a table. If you need to format that table, use the `tbl` object to do so. The way this code is written *requires* a reference to the Word object library (early binding). Note that it's also possible to use late-binding - you'll find loads of examples for that.

The second procedure, `concatData` is called in `Test` to create the character delimited string. It uses a `Tab` character as the field separator and a carriage return as the record separator. Word will accept pretty much anything as the field separator; the record separator *must* be a carriage return (ANSI 13).

```
Sub Test()
    Dim wd As Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim tbl As Word.Table

    Set wd = New Word.Application
    wd.Visible = True
    Set doc = wd.Documents.Add
    Set rng = doc.Content
    rng.Text = concatData()
    Set tbl = rng.ConvertToTable       
End Sub

Public Function concatData() As String
    Dim retVal As String
    Dim rsHeader As Long, rsCounter As Long        
    Dim rs As Recordset

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("nameOfRecordset", dbOpenDynaset)
    'Get headers
    For rsHeader = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        retVal = retVal & rs.Fields(rsHeader).Name & vbTab
    Next
    'Replace last TAb with a carriage return
    retVal = Left(retVal, Len(retVal) - 1) & vbCr

    Do While Not rs.EOF
       'Get all records
        For rsCounter = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            retVal = retVal & rs.Fields(rsCounter).Value & vbTab
        Next
        retVal = Left(retVal, Len(retVal) - 1) & vbCr
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    concatData = retVal
End Function
```